# What's the proper way to reset SELinux?

Tags: redhat, selinux

I'm using REDHAT 6.x and I think something went wrong so I'd like to reset *EVERYTHING* (selinux wise) and just redo it, how would one go about it?

Comment: You'll simply need to reinstall to be sure.

Comment: Please clarify your question -- Do you want to reset *JUST THE SELINUX CONFIGURATION* (as your title suggests), or *EVERYTHING* (as the body of your question states).  The two require vastly different approaches.

Comment: I didn't think RedHat 6.x had selinux, or do you need to clarrify that as well?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers RedHat is, as near as I can tell, the flagship distribution with SELinux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# setenforce 0
# yum erase selinux\*
# rm -rf /etc/selinux
# yum install selinux-policy-targeted 
# touch /.autorelabel
# reboot
```

Comment: How will fiddling with the selinux labels reset the kid back to a base install?

Comment: Because he asked for a "proper way to reset SELinux?"

Comment: *facepalm* I read that as EL Linux. Gods I feel like a jerk.

Comment: @ScottPack Well, he does say he wants to reset "*EVERYTHING*", not  that he wants to reset "*SELinux*", so I think there's plenty of ambiguity to go around...

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in 2 simple steps:

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4096`
2. Provision using the method of your choice onto your freshly cleaned drive.

Answer (score 1):

Format disk, reinstall RHEL 6.

Really the only way to reset "*EVERYTHING*".